# Best way to create components - via using a returning method or void method that creates it?

Tags: java, components

Which is better "practice"?:

```
public JPanel getMyPanel() {
JPanel p = new JPanel;
return p;
}
```

Or:

```
private JPanel panel;
public void createPanel() {
panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(etc)
}
```

Is there a benefit of using instance variables over local variables? Just was curious about the best practices and perhaps if I could improve my way of coding.

Comment: Well building an application needs its foundation. If you place small building blocks (local variables) that get destroyed once the method itself is calculated then the app ultimately has no long term memory and is ...empty. You start with the long term memory blocks, the instance variables, why not, the class variables and then methods that add small pieces or make calculations. But the frame itself should be stored in long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best practice in this case.. it all depends on the app you are developing... sometimes you just don't need to create a new JPanel but instead only once in the constructor...

Now if your app needs a new instance of a JPanel then returning a new Object will be ok too.